# Is there a word that describes all items in a sequence or list which is not the first item?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that can be used to refer to all the items in a list or sequence which is not the first item? For example, take this list:

(oranges, apples, raspberries, pears)

How can I refer to (apples, raspberries, and pears)?

Comment: Well in some computer languages the Head is the first element and the Tail is the rest. However I don't believe there's a normal English word.

Comment: I suspect the question has already been asked and answered here. Possible duplicate http://english.stackexchange.com/a/90067/14666

Comment: Three out of four ain't bad.

Comment: cdr (oranges, apples, raspberries, pears)

Answer (score 0):

You can say,

> All but the first from the list.

*All but* means:

all except: *we have support from all but one of the networks.*